# ¿Todavía tiene connotación divina 'ojalá'? // Does 'ojalá' still have a divine connotation?

Tags: definiciones, religión, connotaciones, árabe

> #### [**ojalá**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QxGRTE0)
>
> Del ár. hisp. *law šá lláh* 'si Dios quiere'.
>
> 1. `interj.` Denota vivo deseo de que suceda algo.

*Ojalá* comes from the Arabic *if God wants it* or *God-willing* but is now defined without reference to a divine figure.

**Is it now entirely secular or does it still carry a divine connotation?**
When someone reads or hears the word do they still read or hear a religious aspect? Would a non-religious person use the word seriously?

**Some English corollaries:**

*Godwilling* - the NOAD definition does not mention God ("used to express the wish that one will be able to do as one intends or that something will happen as planned") but I, as a native English speaker, still very much hear this as a reference to a divine figure and would not use it seriously without religious belief.

*Goodbye* - like *adios* it literally means, etymologically, *God be with you*. It has, however, lost all religious connotations.

Which is more true of *ojalá*?

Comment: Not only it has lost its religious connotations, I dare say that most people does not know it has a religious origin. I am not a religious person and I use it in both colloquial and formal contexts.

Comment: I would say that even people who refuse to say *adiós*, using *salud* instead, because they are aware of their original religious meaning and want to avoid it, would have no problem using *ojalá*.

Comment: Which raises the interesting question of what Spanish speaking followers of Islam say instead when speaking about future events. Anglophones say _insh'allah_ which means if God wills it.

Comment: @mdewey that's a very interesting question. I imagine though that they would then just stick with the Arabic and say inshallah as well

Answer (score 6):

No, it does not.

In both 1780 and 1817 the dictionary defined it as:

> interj. Quiera Dios, asi sea. Úsase siempre para expresar el deseo que tenemos de que suceda alguna cosa que se apetece ó pide con ansia. Utinam.

In 1884 it changed to:

> interj. con que se denota vivo deseo de que suceda una cosa.

And starting in 2001 it is as follows:

> 1. interj. Denota vivo deseo de que suceda algo.

That is, it initially had a religious connotation (*Quiera Dios*) but it has evolved into something popular and cultural.

This could also be the case of *Jesús* as to say *bless you* when sneezing. Neither in Spanish nor in English does this have a literally divine meaning.

Comment: +1. Explained better, impossible.

Comment: I believe *ojalá* is said to be "grammaticalized", i.e. it's not an idiomatic expression anymore but a grammatical marker. IIRC language learners are told that the verb goes in the subjunctive mood in *n* cases, one of them being simply "after *ojalá*". :)

Comment: Your argument was very convincing until you added the parenthetical remark about *Quiera dios*.  The answer would be strengthened by removing this.  In Mexico, at least, there are plenty of people with a deep-seated folk-level religiosity *do* mean it literally when they say, "Si Dios quiere" when talking about, for example, managing to pay the electric bill tomorrow.

Comment: @aparente001 oh, I see. Feel free to change it to make it more Mexico-compliant (in Spain it is rare to feel such power of God for everyday situations).

Comment: @fedorqui - very nice phrase, Mexico-compliant.  // Check if my edit went too far, please.

Comment: @aparente001 it is fine, thanks for teaching me some English by improving my answer!